# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) after sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql*

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp, ubuntu-20.04

**Background:** I am using Ubuntu-20.04 and I needed to downgrade MySQL version from 8.0 to 5.7.

By using multiple tutorials I had not succeeded and then I installed MySQL 8.0 again but now I can not connect with MySQL 8.0.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and got error

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I think the reason was I had run these two commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql*
```

After reinstalling mysql 8.0 i found `/etc/mysql` but there is no directory like `/var/lib/mysql*` .

Please help me to login in mysql, I have tried a lot of solutions. If you have any question, please let me know.

**Some extra Details:**

> usman@usman-Lenovo-V310-15ISK:~$ systemctl status mysql.service

> ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server

> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-08-22 22:46:33 PKT; 22min ago
> Process: 369742 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

> Aug 22 22:46:33 usman-Lenovo-V310-15ISK systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
> Aug 22 22:46:33 usman-Lenovo-V310-15ISK systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
> Aug 22 22:46:33 usman-Lenovo-V310-15ISK systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
> Aug 22 22:46:33 usman-Lenovo-V310-15ISK systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
> Aug 22 22:46:33 usman-Lenovo-V310-15ISK systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me. And its perfect solution as per my problem.

[Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835541/mysql-install-db-on-ubuntu-16-04)